# AMD SP5100 Raid 0 rebuild

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm, raid-0

I was using an onboard AMD SP5100 raid controller for a Raid 0 on two 1TB drives. The motherboard has failed. I have two questions - firstly if I replace with an identical motherboard, will I be able to get the Raid 0 intact? Secondly is it possible to recreate the raid in software. The output from fdisk and mdadm are below

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdd: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c37ea

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sdd2              14      243168  1953142537+  8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/ddf1_root: 2000.1 GB, 2000131457024 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243168 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 131072 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c37ea

                Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/ddf1_rootp1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/mapper/ddf1_rootp2              14      243168  1953142537+  8e  Linux LVM
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/mapper/ddf1_rootp1: 106 MB, 106896384 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 12 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 131072 bytes
Alignment offset: 33280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/ddf1_rootp2: 2000.0 GB, 2000017958400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243155 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 131072 bytes
Alignment offset: 26112 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

madm
[root@office ~]# mdadm --examine /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :       208782 sectors at           63 (type 83)
Partition[1] :   3906285075 sectors at       208845 (type 8e)
[root@office ~]# mdadm --examine /dev/sdc
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get an identical motherboard to have raid support. Raid is supported either as its own hardware card or onboard.

Now, for your next question the difference between hardware raid and software raid is that hardware raid has its own resources independent of the host to present to the host that the hard drives connected to the raid controller as just 1 hard drive. Software raid utilizes the resources of the host instead as a piece of software. Software raid generally has slower performance than Hardware raid support. However they both work the same. So if you are needing to get the data off the Hard drives you could use software raid on another computer to do this or you can simply wait till you get a new motherboard that has raid support built in or buy a raid controller.

Comment: Will I be able to recover the data intact from the RAID 0 on a different RAID controller?

Comment: Yes as long as the controller supports Raid 0 which it most likely does you can recover the data same with software raid.